# What's the size of K in this figure?

Tags: problem-solving

What's the size of K in this figure?

[image]

A and a are parallel
B and b are parallel

Answer (score 4):

Here's the diagram with some new lines drawn:
[image]

Because the line segments of length $A$ and $a$, and the line segments of length $B$ and $b$, respectively, are parallel, the triangles are right triangles. Therefore, by the Pythagorean theorem, we have that $K^2=(A-a)^2+d^2$ and $K^2=(B-b)^2+d^2$, so
$$K=\sqrt{(A-a)^2+d^2}=\sqrt{(B-b)^2+d^2}.$$