# Problem related "polygon offseting"

Tags: euclidean-geometry

[image]

Knowing points P1,P2,P3 and distance d and the angles shown in the figure, angle between a and b not necessary 90º

What's the size of K?

Comment: possible duplicate of [What's the size of K in this figure?](http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/126416/whats-the-size-of-k-in-this-figure)

Comment: Is not the same problem, please read it again.

Comment: I agree it is not quite the same problem.  Sorry.  If you are the same user, please ask that the accounts be merged.

Comment: No same user, just used similar scheme, could you not downgrade my question if you do it?

Answer (score 2):

It may be convenient to represent this in the complex plane, with $P2 = 0$.  Let the three vertices on the top of the figure be $P4$, $P5$, $P6$ from left to right.  Now 
$P4 = P1 (1 - i d/a)$, $P6 = P3 (1 + i d/b)$.  $P5 = P4 - s P1 = P6 - t P3$ where $s$ and $t$ are real.  Solve $s P1 - t P3 = P4 - P6$ and $s \overline{P1} - t \overline{P3} = \overline{P4-P6}$, obtaining $s$ and $t$ and thus $P5$.  Then $k = |P5 - P2|$.

Answer (score 0):

Knowing $P_1,P_2,P_3$, you can use the law of cosines to work out the angle at $P_2$. Drop a perpendicular from $P_2$ to a point $Q$ on the line segment parallel to the segment of length $a$, and another to the point $R$ on the line segment parallel to the segment of length $b$. This makes two congruent little right triangles, so you can work out the angle of either one of them at $P_2$. Now for these little right triangles you have an angle and a side, $d$, so you can get the hypotenuse, $k$.